# Is it ok to have a Controller class that facilitates communication between other classes?

Tags: java, oop

I have object A and object B. Is it ok to create object C who's soul purpose is to create object A and B, and facilitate communication between them?

For instance object A does function A. When function A executes object C is notified and tells object B what to do.

Is this ok? Wouldn't this be a good example of loose coupling? Or could this be designed better?

Comment: Seems appropriate to me...although that's just my *opinion*.

Comment: It sounds okay. It's a form of loose coupling and will make the testing possibly easier. Does `C` do anything functional other than just relaying messages though? If it doesn't then there is little advantage over just coupling `A` and `B` through an interface.

Comment: No C doesn't do much else. In fact, if I find myself adding any functionality to object C I usually end up extracting this out into another class.

Answer (score 1):

If you seek for loose coupling between two or more objects, you may want to implement the [Mediator](http://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html) pattern:

> **Intent:** Define an object that encapsulates how a set of objects interact.
>   Mediator promotes loose coupling by keeping objects from referring to
>   each other explicitly, and it lets you vary their interaction
>   independently.